# A sentence that must consist of 終わられる, しまう, and よう

Tags: grammar

Is my sentence below correct? What I want to say is

> This textbook seems to be finished before Friday this week.

My attempt is as follows,

> 今週{こんしゅう}の金曜日｛きんようび｝の前｛まえ｝にこの教｛きょう｝科｛か｝書｛しょ｝が終｛お｝わられてしまうようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

> 今週の金曜(日)までに、この教科書は終わりそうです。or 終わってしまいそうです。

Comment: Though I didn't use 終わられる or よう. The そう is 様態, not 伝聞. If you combine られる+しまう+ようだ, you get られてしまうようだ. eg. [食べられてしまうようだ, 片付けられてしまうようだ, 載せられてしまうようだ, etc.](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=pze_VbGnGsXs0gSlsbOgCA#q=%22%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0%22&newwindow=1&start=0)

Answer (score 1):

終わる is an intransitive verb. You can simply say

> 今週の金曜日の前に、この教科書は終わるようです。

In this case, the passive form doesn't sound natural.

Things without feelings couldn't be a subject in a passive sentence in old Japanese. After a lot of books in European languages were translated into Japanese, people started to use 'things without soul' as a subject in a passive sentence. The usage, however, is still fairly limited.

Comment: 降る is an intransitive verb but we can say 僕は雨に降られた. I quoted it from a book titled A dictionary of basic Japanese grammar which is written by Seiichi Makino and Michio Tsutsui.

Comment: "終わる is an intransitive verb" >> Yeah, but you know what? 終わる can be transitive, too! eg これで会議を終わります。

Comment: @FriendlyGhost The passive form in 僕は雨に降られた is a so-called "迷惑の受身". 僕 is complaining about the rain.

Comment: @choco I know. You cannot say これで会議は終わられます, though. See my edit in the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with my answer but as far as I know, -てしまう is only been use for unintentional action. maybe you can drop that part nad make it like this 今週の金曜日にはこの教科書を終わったようんだ but I am not sure with my answer

Comment: ～てしまう can also be used to convey a meaning of "~ has been done completely".

Comment: What is ようんだ? A typo for ようだ?

Comment: 。。。。。。。。。ようなんだ？